# onClick event that checks if an array includes the element

Tags: javascript

I have an array of state which is controlled through a dropdown.

This is state held like:

```
    const [finalselected, setfinalSelected] = useState([]);
```

When a submit button is clicked, I would like to confirm that an element does not already exist in the array, for example an individual cannot input "experience": "A similar role" 10 times into the array.

My current function does not stop additional elements coming if it is a duplicate:

```
    const onSubmitFinalSelection = (val) => {
    
        if (!finalselected.includes(selectedExperience)) {
            //if finalselected does NOT include the element, then add in a new element
            // setfinalSelected((prev) => [...prev, selectedExperience, inputfield]);
            
        setfinalSelected((prevFinalSelection) => [
            ...prevFinalSelection,
            {
                //this is the dropdown
                experience: selectedExperience,
                //this is an input
                inputfield, 
            },
        ]);
        }

        console.log(finalselected)
      };
```

How would you re-write this?

Comment: why not hide the one that is added

Comment: I would like to use smart logic to make this an efficent process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? I don't think the `includes` function works with the selectedExperience as single parameter since the array contains objects.

```js
    const onSubmitFinalSelection = (val) => {
        // If found, return
        if (finalselected.some(x => x.experience === selectedExperience)) 
          return;
            
        setfinalSelected([...finalSelected, {
                //this is the dropdown
                experience: selectedExperience,
                //this is an input
                inputfield, 
        }])
        
        console.log(finalsSlected)
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Alerting if the element is already inside my array if not doing normal push.

```js
let selectedValues = document.querySelector(".selectedValues");
let array = [];

function myFunction(option) {
  option = option.value;
  if (array.includes(option)) {
    alert(option + " "+ "is already selected")
  } else {
    array.push(option);
  }
  selectedValues.textContent = array;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="selectedValues" type="text"></textarea>

<select onchange="myFunction(this)" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```